# gData+Python Calendar API - Doesn't update?

Tags: python, calendar, gdata

I'm trying to write a python script that I can crontab to pull about a week's worth of google calendar appointments, and take any with a Hangout attached and add the link into some visible area where OSX iCal can pick it up.

My project is on github at https://github.com/Yeraze/CalendarHangout

Right now it appears to work.  It finds about 20 entries on my calendar, properly pulls the link and updates them, and then submits a batch update of 20 items back to google.  However, I'm seeing some weirdness that I can't debug:

1) Several of the events have disappeared from the GCal website.  They still show on all my i-devices and OSX Calendar (even after multiple forced refreshes), but they've disappeared from the website.

2) Every time I run the script, it still says these items need to be updated, like nothing's actually updating.

Can someone with some more experience on this help?  What am I missing?

*Update* Seems they've been converted into something like the Weather icons.. I see them as little boxes at the top, right under all-day events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this... Seems this isn't really supported in V2 of the API.  I've upgraded to V3, found similar glitches, and opened a new question .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321632/gdata-api-v3-calendar-hangouts-urls-and-attachments